# Passing GridSearchCV results to an Imbalanced-Learn's Pipeline object

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, imblearn

Funny issue here - I have `GridSearchCV` results, which after cherry-picking from `grid_search_cv.results_` attribute are captured as follows:

```
Input: pd.DataFrame(grid_clf_rf.cv_results_).iloc[4966]['params']

Output: {'rf__max_depth': 40, 'rf__max_features': 2, 'rf__n_estimators': 310}
```

Now, as I understand, Imbalanced Learn package's Pipeline object is a wrapper around SciKit-Learn's Pipeline, and it should accept `**fit_params` parameter in it's `.fit()` method, as follows:

```
clf = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(random_state = random_state, 
                                 n_jobs = n_jobs)

pipeline = Pipeline([('nt', nt), ('rf', clf)])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, **pd.DataFrame(grid_clf_rf.cv_results_).iloc[4966]['params'])
```

However, when I execute the above expression, I get the following result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a26424dc8038> in <module>
      4 pipeline = Pipeline([('nt', nt), ('rf', clf)])
      5 
----> 6 pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, **pd.DataFrame(grid_clf_rf.cv_results_).iloc[4966]['params'])
      7 
      8 print_scores(pipeline, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imblearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    237         Xt, yt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    238         if self._final_estimator is not None:
--> 239             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, yt, **fit_params)
    240         return self
    241 

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_features'
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume you come up with a set of hyper parameters something as following

```
hyper_params=  {'rf__max_depth': 40, 'rf__max_features': 2, 'rf__n_estimators': 310}
```

As mentioned by @ Parthasarathy Subburaj, these are not `fit_params`. We can set these params for a classifier inside a pipeline using `.set_params()` option

```
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedRandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=3,
                           n_informative=4, weights=[0.2, 0.3, 0.5],
                           random_state=0)

clf = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)

pipeline = Pipeline([ ('rf', clf)])

hyper_params=  {'rf__max_depth': 40, 'rf__max_features': 2, 'rf__n_estimators': 310}
pipeline.set_params(**hyper_params)

pipeline.fit(X,y)

#
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('rf',
                 BalancedRandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True,
                                                class_weight=None,
                                                criterion='gini', max_depth=40,
                                                max_features=2,
                                                max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                                min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                                                min_samples_leaf=2,
                                                min_samples_split=2,
                                                min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                                                n_estimators=310, n_jobs=1,
                                                oob_score=False, random_state=0,
                                                replacement=False,
                                                sampling_strategy='auto',
                                                verbose=0, warm_start=False))],
         verbose=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you feeding in the dataframe containing the parameters to build your model to your `.fit()` method, it just takes two arguments your X and y. You need to pass in your parameters of the model to`BalancedRandomForestClassifier` constructor. Since your parameter names doesn't match with the ones which [BalancedRandomForestClassifier](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedRandomForestClassifier.html) takes you need to feed it manually like this

```
clf = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 40, max_features = 2, n_estimators = 310, random_state = random_state, n_jobs = n_jobs)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was already aware of that possibility. What I need is the ability to load GridSearchCV's output into a .fit() method of the pipeline due to other reasons.

Comment: In that case you can try the `.best_params_` which is an attribute of gridsearch object which returns a dictionary of the best set of parameters, with keys being the parameter names and values being the value of the parameter itself.